# No me carga nada React JS - Error basico

Tags: reactjs

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente codigo actualmente estoy creando un React to List , basandome en este tutorial: [El tutorial](https://www.kirupa.com/react/simple_todo_app_react.htm)

El codigo esta bien no me suelta ningun error ni el inspector de codigo del navegador..

lo estoy ejecutando desde localHost con el LAMP en ubuntu.

Quiza debo instalar algo pero alguien conoce que cosa debo instalar?

**Mi codigo:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
<head>
  <title>React! React! React!</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
  
<body>
  
  <div id="container">
  
  </div>
  
  <script type="text/script">
   var TodoList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
      return (
        <div className="todoListMain">
          <div className="header">
            <form>
              <input placeholder="enter task">
              </input>
              <button type="submit">add</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
});
  </script>
</body>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un par de errores.
El primero, que estás usando `<script type="text/script">` cuando en el ejemplo sale que debes usar `<script type="text/babel">`. Esto es porque usas la librería `babel-core` para poder ejecutar código jsx sin problemas (los browsers no son capaces de soportarlo). En un ambiente mas profesional la idea es que no se use este tipo de librerías, sino realizar la compilación de jsx a js a nivel de servidor, pero eso ya es tema para otra pregunta y si estás aprendiendo, es suficiente con como lo estás haciendo.
Lo otro es que solo estás creando la clase react, pero no estás llamando a `ReactDOM.render` para poder mostrar la clase ni tampoco especificando donde quieres realizar el render de la clase, que para este caso sería en el `<div id="container">`.
Corrigiendo eso, tu código quedaría como:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>React! React! React!</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">

  </div>

  <script type="text/babel">
    var TodoList = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
          return (
            <div className="todoListMain">
              <div className="header">
                <form>
                  <input placeholder="enter task">
                  </input>
                  <button type="submit">add</button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }
    });

    var destination = document.querySelector("#container");
    ReactDOM.render(
      <div>
        <TodoList/>
      </div>,
      destination
    );
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias amigos viendo tu codigo si me faltaban muchas cosas :)